# Cannot use utf-8 encoded image filename in order to customize node shape

Tags: graphviz

I've saved DOT code file in utf-8 encoding. But it cannot output png image file with customized shape. Is there an example to demonstrate user specified charset usage of graphviz?

The demo code is here.

```
digraph G {

    bgcolor=black;
    edge [arrowsize=1, color=red];

    node [penwidth=1, color=white, labelloc=b];

    BR [shape=box, label="BR", charset="utf-8", image="图元.png"];
    DS [shape=plaintext, fontname="SimSun", fontcolor=white, fontsize=18, label="测点"];
    BR -> DS[dir=forward];
}
```

And the results of command-line are listed as following.

```
C:\dot>dot -Gcharset=utf-8 -Tpng -o demo.png demo.dot
Warning: No such file or directory while opening 鍥惧厓.png
Warning: No or improper image="鍥惧厓.png" for node "BR"
```

Comment: GraphViz uses iconv to convert encoding. Why cannot use utf-8 image file name?

Comment: It works fine for me, on OS X 10.6.8 on a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) file system. What operating system are you using, and what kind of file system are the files on? Graphviz defaults to UTF-8 encoding for parsing the graph, so you don't need to specify that on the command line, nor is it valid to specify it in the node definition. But it might not be trying to convert filename encodings. / You've also asked multiple questions here; you should ask just a single question in each Stack Overflow post.

Answer (score 0):

There is an encoding problem somewhere in the chain. The image file name in the source is `图元.png` but when graphviz reads it, it sees `鍥惧厓.png`.

This suggests that you didn't save the file as UTF-8 or that the default encoding of your OS isn't UTF-8. I couldn't find a way to tell graphviz the encoding of the source in the documentation. The option `charset` is only used "when interpreting string input as a text label." (see also "[Character encodings](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language)")

So it will not solve your problem. One solution is to replace Unicode characters with the HTML entity. So you could use `"&#22294;&#20803;.png"` but again, the documentation says "During label evaluation, these entities are translated" which probably means they're not translated anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem on Windows 10, and solved it by checking the checkbox "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Windows Control Panel.